# What is the shortest/most idiomatic way of determining whether a variable is any one of a list of values?

Tags: ruby, syntax

This seems a ridiculously simple question to be asking, but what's the shortest/most idiomatic way of rewriting this in Ruby?

```
if variable == :a or variable == :b or variable == :c or variable == :d # etc.
```

I saw this solution:

```
if [:a, :b, :c, :d].include? variable
```

but this isn't always functionally equivalent - I believe `Array#include?` actually looks to see if the variable object is contained in the list; it doesn't take into account that the object may implement its own equality test with `def ==(other)`.

As observed by helpful commentators below, that explanation isn't correct. `include?` does use `==` but it uses the `==` method of the items in the array. In my example, it's the symbols, rather than the `==` method of the variable. That explains why it's not equivalent to my first code example.

(Take, for example, Rails' `Mime::Type` implementation: `request.format == :html` may return true, but `[:html].include?(request.format)` will return false, as `request.format` is an instance of Mime::Type, not a symbol.)

The best I have so far is:

```
if [:a, :b, :c, :d].select {|f| variable == f}.any?
```

but it seems somewhat cumbersome to me. Does anyone have better suggestions?

Comment: I think that the "Any" syntax seems pretty clean.  But, I'm C# and tt sorta mirrors how LINQ looks, so I'm biased.

Comment: The documentations states: Array#include? Returns true if the given object is present in self (that is, if any object == anObject), false otherwise.

Comment: I wonder if implementing a isOneOf?( array ) method in the Object class is not considered a good practice in ruby, I mean, messing around with base classes (obviously, I have no experience with ruby)... anyway, it would be fine if someone can post such a method....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, `#include?` *does* use `==`.  The problem arises from the fact that if you do

```
[:a].include? foo
```

it checks `:a == foo`, not `foo == :a`.  That is, it uses the `==` method defined on the objects in the Array, not the variable.  Therefore you can use it so long as you make sure the objects in the array have a proper `==` method.

In cases where that won't work, you can simplify your statement by removing the `select` statement and passing the block directly to `any`:

```
if [:a, :b, :c, :d].any? {|f| variable == f}
```

Comment: Aha! I think you've nailed my #include? problem - thank you, that makes perfect sense.

Back to the problem at hand, I also like your method of passing a block to any? - that looks very clean to me.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `Array#include?` does use `==`:

```
>> class AString < String
>>   def ==(other)
>>     self[0] == other[0]
>>   end
>> end

>> asdf = AString.new "asdfg"
=> "asdfg"
>> b = AString.new 'aer'
=> "aer"

>> asdf == b
=> true

>> [asdf].include? b
=> true
```

The [`Array#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002203) documentation also explains this.

Comment: Thanks for your analysis; it's appreciated. I was being fooled by the problem Pesto observes above, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used your second example, `if [:a, :b, :c, :d].include? variable`.  While this does present some problems with classes that overwrite `==`, it's perfectly fine in most situations I've needed it (usually checking against symbols).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I got bitten today by [:html, :xml].include?(request.format) always returning false in a Rails app, so I was thinking I might need to get myself out of that habit!

Comment: Perhaps you could write `[:html, :xml].include?(request.format.to_sym)`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
 if [:a, :b, :c, :d].index variable
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's appreciated. I think that exhibits the same behaviour as #include?, though - presumably for the same reason Pesto explains in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really doing is seeing if variable is a member of the set `[:a,:b,:c,:d]` so semantically that maps to the `include?`  method.

The problem you encounter is due to the duck-typing nature of Ruby so if you want to get around that why not first convert to a symbol:

```
if [:a, :b, :c, :d].include? variable.to_sym
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's apprecited. That works in a lot of cases, but of course won't work if the object in question implements further logic in its definition of equality. (Perhaps it also compares against a list of synonyms, for example.)